# Define data transformer invalid_message error in entity class with translations

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have made a Data Transformer for my User class on a form field. It is for users to enter another username to which they want to send a private message to. It also has a title and content, but that doesn't matter, for now.

Here is the form builder:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('content', 'textarea')
        ->add(
            'receiver',
            'text',
            array(
                // validation message if the data transformer fails
                'invalid_message' => 'That is not a valid user',
            )
        );

    $builder->get('receiver')->addModelTransformer(new UserTransformer($this->manager));
}
```

What I want to do is get the `invalid_message` error and put it into a translation file. The problem is that I have to write it here:

```
->add('receiver',
      'text',
       array('invalid_message' => 'user.invalid')
```

Which will be taken from my translations.

Is there a way to have this message in my Entity class along with all the other validators, instead of having it in the form type class? I don't want to spread my validation messages everywhere in my files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, if you really want to store all the message translation keys in your entity, you could store those in a constant array in your entity class.

For example, your entity class may look like :

```
//..
class Foo
{
    const MESSAGES = [
        'invalidUser' => 'user.invalid'
    ];

    public static function getMessages()
    {
        return self::MESSAGES;
    }

    //..
}
```

and in your data transformer :

```
->add('receiver',
      'text', [
           'invalid_message' => Foo::getMessages()['invalidUser']
       ]
```

Still I am failing to fully understand the motivation behind this. You will need at some point to identify the message you want to display in your data transformer. So what is the point to not provide directly the translation key associated to this message, and instead retrieve it through the entity ?

The place where your messages should be gathered is only the translation file. The validators in your entity class, as well as your data transformer, are only there to provide the good translation keys.

Comment: It didn't make much sense to me to have validator text both in the entity class and my data transformer. I like your idea, but it seems not worth the trouble, so I'll stick to keeping it in the transformer.